# How to prevent user Input from being carried over when exception is thrown?

Tags: java, object, exception, methods

I don't know if its the lack of sleep, but I just can't see why this is happening.

I have my code which asks for an `int` value from the user. If the user types some stupid thing like "twenty seven" instead of any number, it will throw an `InputMismatchException` exception. All this is fine.

For some reason, the user input value gets carried on to my code after which messes everything up...

```
case 'r':
     System.out.print("What height to reap at  : ");
         try {
             reapAt = keyboard.nextInt();
             canadaforestservice.reapTrees(initTreeHeight, initTreeGrowPerYear, reapAt);
             } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
             System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid height");
             }
             System.out.println();
             System.out.print("(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it : ");
             menuItems = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
             break;
```

Expected Result:

(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it : r

What height to reap at  : twenty seven

ERROR: Invalid height

(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :

---

My Result:

(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it : r

What height to reap at  : twenty seven

ERROR: Invalid height

**(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :  ERROR: Invalid option, try again** **"The letter T gets carried over from previous user input"**

(D)isplay, (N)ew, (Y)ear, (R)eap, (S)ave, (L)oad, e(X)it :

Answer (score 0):

Inside `catch (InputMismatchException e)` add the following line: `keyboard.nextLine();` in order to finish reading that line:

```
         // ...
         } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
           System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid height");
           keyboard.nextLine();
         }
         // ...
```

You may want to read the difference between [Scanner#nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) which

> Scans the **next token** of the input as an int

and [Scanner#nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) which

> Advances this scanner **past the current line** and returns the input that
>   was skipped